# Insufficient Permission Error 403 : Google Drive Upload (Python)

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to access Google Drive using the Drive API Version 3 (Python). Listing the files seems to work fine. I get insufficient Permission error when I try to upload a file.

I changed My scope to give full permission to my script

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
```

Below is the block that I use to create the file

```
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'Contents.pdf',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.file'
}
media = MediaFileUpload('Contents.pdf',
                        mimetype='application/vnd.google-apps.file',
                        resumable=True)
file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print ('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
```

I get this error message:

ResumableUploadError: HttpError 403 "Insufficient Permission"

I am not sure what is wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your script works fine. From the error you show, I thought the requirement of reauthorize of access token and refresh token. So please try a following flow.

When you authorize using `client_secret.json`, a credential JSON file is created. At the default Quickstart, it is created in `.credentials` of your home directory.

**For your current situation, please delete your current the credential JSON file which is not `client_secret.json`, and reauthorize by launching your script. The default file name of Quickstart is `drive-python-quickstart.json`.**

By this, scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` is reflected to access token and refresh token, and they are used for uploading process. When the error occurs even if this flow is done, please confirm whether Drive API is enabled at API console, again.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: I tried this option. This seems to work. I think the reason is when I initially created the quickstart.json file I created with a different scope. When I changed the scope it did not update in the file. When I deleted and recreated the file, the upload was successful.

Comment: @Subu Ganesh I'm relieved to hear that this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already have a file with the same name there?

Comment: No , this is a new file. I tried to create a folder instead of a file. It results with the same error. Listing files work with no issues. I am not sure if I am missing to grant permission anywhere.

Comment: Try to follow this example https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads